# How can I use GDB to debug code with signal handling?

Tags: gdb

I am running below code in debug. As soon as parent process receives a signal the debugger show that I am in parent handler code on stepping in. But from there on , I have no control over GDB. It enters some file when I hit continue and stops with following message:

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
_dl_runtime_resolve () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-trampoline.S:34
34  ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-trampoline.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) continue
```

And when I try to continue , it repeats with new files.

Output of show follow-fork-mode and show detach-on-fork

```
(gdb) b 78
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400bba: file main.c, line 78.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/samkit/Posix_Programming/unix_Simple_prodcon_con_prob/main 
Child sending signal

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf48) at main.c:79

79      if(cpid==0){

(gdb) show follow-fork-mode

Debugger response to a program call of fork or vfork is "parent".

(gdb) show detach-on-fork

Whether gdb will detach the child of a fork is on.

(gdb)
```

Also tried switching to child process in GDB , setting breakpoint at line 78 and then RUN. Child process sends signal to parent and receives SIGUSR2 from parent. And hence enters its own handler. And after that the GDB is not able to return(similar to above) Below is the output:

```
(gdb) set follow-fork-mode child
(gdb) set detach-on-fork on
(gdb) b 78
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400bba: file main.c, line 78.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/samkit/Posix_Programming/unix_Simple_prodcon_con_prob/main 
[New process 31109]
[Switching to process 31109]

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf48) at main.c:79
79      if(cpid==0){
(gdb) next
83          if((child_sm_id = shmget(key,size*sizeof(char),0))==-1){    // Allocate shared memory
(gdb) next
87          if((child_sm_ptr = shmat(child_sm_id,NULL,0)) == (void *)-1){       // Attach shared memory to your address space
(gdb) next
 95             printf("Child sending signal\n");
(gdb) next

Child sending signal
96              kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
(gdb) next
Received Signal 10
Sending signal

Program received signal SIGUSR2, User defined signal 2.
0x00007ffff7a4b267 in kill () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) next
childHandler (sig=0) at main.c:25
25  void childHandler(int sig){
(gdb) next
26      printf("Child received Signal %d\n",sig);
(gdb) next

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00000000004006e6 in printf@plt ()
(gdb) next
Single stepping until exit from function printf@plt,
which has no line number information.
0x00000000004006b0 in ?? ()
(gdb) next
Cannot find bounds of current function
(gdb)
```

I also tried continue but I think since GDB saw a TRAP , it is re-executing the TRAP again and again , if I try continue.

```
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00000000004006b6 in ?? ()
(gdb) ccontinue
Undefined command: "ccontinue".  Try "help".
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
_dl_runtime_resolve () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-trampoline.S:34
34  ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-trampoline.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
```

Now my questions:

Q1) How can I make GDB actually continue with the execution ?
Q2) I have 2 processes.If I put a breakpoint after fork and do info threads, it shows 1 process and 1 thread. Shouldn't it show 2 processes ?

Code:

```
# include  <signal.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/fcntl.h>
# include <sys/shm.h>
# include <sys/ipc.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 1024

struct smbuffer{
 char buffer[1024];
 int count;
};

void parentHandler(int sig){
   printf("Received Signal %d\n",sig);
 }

void childHandler(int sig){
   printf("Child received Signal %d\n",sig);
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
/* Child related attributes */
pid_t cpid;
int status;
int retval;

/* Shared memory initialization */
int sm_id;
struct smbuffer *sm_ptr;
key_t key = 1100;
int size = BUFF_SIZE;


if((sm_id = shmget(key , size * sizeof(char) , 0666|IPC_CREAT))== -1){  // Allocate shared memory

    perror("SHMGET Failed : \n");
    exit(1);
}

if((sm_ptr = shmat(sm_id,NULL,0))==(void *)-1){ // Attach shared memory to your address space

    perror("SHMAT Failed : \n");
    exit(1);
}

// Intilitialing Signals and handler
struct sigaction childold;  
struct sigaction childnew;
childnew.sa_handler = childHandler;
sigset_t childmask ;
sigemptyset(&childmask);
childnew.sa_mask = childmask;
childnew.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction(SIGUSR2,&childnew,&childold);

// Intilitialing Signals and handler
struct sigaction parentold; 
struct sigaction parentnew;
parentnew.sa_handler = parentHandler;
sigset_t parentmask ;
sigemptyset(&parentmask);
parentnew.sa_mask = parentmask;
parentnew.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction(SIGUSR1,&parentnew,&parentold);


if((cpid = fork())== -1){
    perror("Fork Failed :\n");
}

if(cpid==0){
    /* Child code */
    struct smbuffer *child_sm_ptr; 
    int child_sm_id ;
    if((child_sm_id = shmget(key,size*sizeof(char),0))==-1){    // Allocate shared memory
        perror("Child shmget failed :\n");
        exit(2);
    }   
    if((child_sm_ptr = shmat(child_sm_id,NULL,0)) == (void *)-1){       // Attach shared memory to your address space
        perror("Child shmat failed :\n");
        exit(2);
    }


    // Signal parent and wait for signal from parent. Loop 
    while(1){
        printf("Child sending signal\n");
        kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
        sigsuspend(&childmask);
        sleep(1);
    }

    if(shmdt(child_sm_ptr)==-1){            // De-attach shared memory
        perror("Child shmdt failed :\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    printf("Child exit\n");
    return 0;
}

else{
    /* Parent code */

    // Wait for child signal and signal child. Loop 
    while(1){   
        sigsuspend(&parentmask);
        printf("Sending signal\n");
        kill(cpid,SIGUSR2);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

if(shmdt(sm_ptr)==-1){          // De-attach shared memory
    perror("SHMDT failed :\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Free shared memory
    if((shmctl(sm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL)) == -1){
        perror("Shmctl failed \n");
            exit(1);
    }

printf("End of code\n");
return 0;

} // End of main
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `show follow-fork-mode` and `show detach-on-fork`  ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have updated the post with outputs

Comment: Answer to Q2: when `detach-on-fork` is on (the default), gdb will not control the child, and `info threads` will show only the parent. If you do `set detach-on-fork off` in gdb before the target forks, `info threads` will show both processes. I cannot reproduce problem you're having in Q1, but line main.c:79 in your gdb session is actually line 64 in the code you provided, so perhaps there is some additional code we don't see that is causing the problem.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I truly appreciate your help. +1 for the ans to 2nd question. And -1 to me for adding the stale version of code snippet :( . I have pulled the SIGACTION in parent body before child is forked. This will ensure that both SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 have been modified before child starts. But still if you now put a break point at line 78 i.e. After fork , at the breakpoint itself the child is sending the Signal(may be coz GDB is managing parent and hence slower than child) . Can you please try it once more if now you can reproduce my Q1 problem. I am still seeing the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick : I tried GDB with mode switched to Child. It sends signal and also receives a signal :) ! But now the same problem , as Child receives signal it enters its handler and I am not able to continue. I have added GDB output for child. You can see child cant continue once it enters handler. Do I have to disable SIGTRAP for GDB ?

Comment: Thanks. With the new code, the problem is reproducible now. In fact, I can reproduce it with just `void sighandler(sig) {} main() { signal(SIGUSR1, sighandler); kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1); puts("Hello\n"); }`. Single-stepping that starts within a signal handler results in the target stopping because of a SIGTRAP at every succeeding call to a shared library routine. May be a bug.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick : You mean bug in GDB ? Because my code runs freely without any deadlock when ran normally. Also can disabling SIGTRAP help to solve it or is there a way to move around (i.e. Telling GDB to ignore SIGTRAP and continue as if there was no TRAP) ? I am very new to all this and I have bare minimum knowledge of GDB. I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: It might be a bug in gdb. `handle SIGTRAP nostop` and `handle SIGTRAP noprint` will let you get further along, but it may impact gdb's ability to do breakpoints.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarkPlotnick !! I am atleast able to to proceed by doing noprint and nostop :) . Thank you so much for your time and awesome replies. I learnt a lot !